# DropWizard Serving Assets help needed

Tags: java, yaml, pom.xml, dropwizard

Help! I've been trying for hours, googling anything I could think of. I have a problem, that I would like to show my static content instead of my application on my site.
I modified a simple hello-world application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    new HelloWorldApplication().run(args);
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "hello-world";
}

@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<HelloWorldConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/assets/*", "/"));
}

@Override
public void run(HelloWorldConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) {
    final HelloWorldResource resource = new HelloWorldResource(
            configuration.getTemplate(),
            configuration.getDefaultName()
        );
    final AddResource addResource = new AddResource();
    final DeleteResource deleteResource = new DeleteResource();
    final TemplateHealthCheck healthCheck = new TemplateHealthCheck(configuration.getTemplate());
    environment.healthChecks().register("template", healthCheck);
    environment.jersey().register(resource);
    environment.jersey().register(addResource);
    environment.jersey().register(deleteResource);
}
```

Here's my hello-world.yml:

```
server:
  type: simple
  applicationContextPath: /application/hello-world

template: Hello, %s!
defaultName: Stranger
```

I applied everything, what the DropWizard docs (http://dropwizard.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/core.html#serving-assets) said. But I just cannot manage to reach the index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it working by using the default constructor for the AssetsBundle() class.

With the default constructor your resources will gets looked up in a directory on the java classpath e.g.

```
/src/main/resources/assets/
```

and your have to name your applicationContextPath only /application

Point your browser to the folling location for static content

```
localhost:8080/application/assets/index.htm
```

Comment: Wow thanks a lot finally someone solved this mistery.

Comment: I conclude that the original desired setup is therefore not possible: serve a static bundle from the '/' path and serving the Jersey application from a subpath.

Answer (score 6):

I have not seen an actual example that proves that the documented way actually works.
And when looking in the Dropwizard source, I conclude that this is in fact not possible: the Jetty application context is set by the configuration parameter `applicationContextPath` in `SimpleServerFactory:103`:

```
environment.getApplicationContext().setContextPath(applicationContextPath);
```

And after that, the `AssetBundle`s are registered into this applicationContext upon `run()` (`AssetBundle:109`):

```
environment.servlets().addServlet(assetsName, createServlet()).addMapping(uriPath + '*');
```

So, assetbundles are always served *within* the `applicationContextPath` that is set in the application's YAML file, so serving them *outside* this applicationContextPath is not possible (despite the docs saying so)

A better way to get this working, is to configure the application to use the `/` path:

```
applicationContextPath: /
```

And then, in your application's code, in the `bootstrap()` and `run()` methods, explicitly override the path for Jersey resources and add AssetBundles to your liking:

```
bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/static", "/"));

environment.jersey().setUrlPattern("/application/*");
```

Comment: Thanks! This is the only way I have tried that actually works.

Comment: This is a proper solution and worked for me too. After some digging around this work around was also presented in Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dropwizard-user/UaVcAYm0VlQ

Comment: This has changed in DropWizard 0.8.x.  http://knowm.org/migrating-dropwizard-from-0-7-x-to-0-8-0/

Answer (score 1):

For Dropwizard 0.8.0 and newer this is achieved from this configuration:

```
applicationContextPath: /
rootPath: /application
```

Where applicationContextPath is Jetty's Context path, and rootPath is Jersey's.

Answer (score 0):

As Geert mentioned, the asset bundle needs to be served from within the applicationContextPath.  However, if you add the AssetsBundle in the bootstrap method, and set the contextPath from the run method, the AssetServlet gets added after the contextPath is set.

My fix is to avoid using the AssetsBundle and add the AssetsServlet directly in the run method (after contextPath is set):

```
environment.getApplicationContext().setContextPath("/");
environment.servlets().addServlet("assets", new AssetServlet("/assets", "/", "index.html", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).addMapping("/*");
```